# How to implement ViewPager with fragments in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

since Google introduced androidX I'm having a problem with viewpager. I want to make a tab layout where I can swipe between fragments. 
getSupportFragmentManager() is deprecated now and shows an error

```
ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, int) in ViewPagerAdapter cannot be applied to (FragmentManager)
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new RecentFragment();
            case 1:
                return new TracksFragment();
            case 2:
                return new AlbumFragment();
            case 3:
                return new GenresFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

and in my activity I need to call it

```
 ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
 viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

I found the solution, in the constructor I have second paremeters and in the viewpager I added page position and is working fine.

```
public static int PAGE_POSITION = 4;

 ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), PAGE_POSITION));
TabLayout tab = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ViewPagerAdapter` class has a constructor that takes 2 parameters.
When you try to create a new `ViewPagerAdapter`, you only use 1 parameter.
Which is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Look at the documentation for the `FragmentPagerAdapter` class and see what the 2nd parameter should be.

Comment: Yes you are right, it needs a second paremeter which was page position.

Comment: Oh god no, don't use page position. 
When you start, the position is 0, so it will technically be the correct value, but things will go very wrong if the initial position is not 0 or 1 at some point.
Read the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html#FragmentPagerAdapter(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,%20int)

Answer (score 1):

use `getChildFragmentManager` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewPager2 to create swipe view and the adapter class must extend FragmentStateAdapter. 
ex:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this);
    final ViewPager2 viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager,
            new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    tab.setText("OBJECT " + (position + 1));
                   viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition(),true);
                }
            }
    ).attach();

}
```